# A Database Error Occurred Error Number: 1046 in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, mysql-error-1046

A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1046

No database selected

SELECT * FROM `ts_themes` WHERE `theme_status` = 1

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/Themeportal/application/models/DatabaseModel.php

Line Number: 23

Comment: Please provide more information about your environment or what you are trying to do.

Comment: Follow the class and file naming way for codeigniter https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming `Database_model.php` and `class Database_model extends CI_Model {}`

Answer (score 1):

Manage your database setting in `application/config/database.php`

```
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
'dsn'      => '',
'hostname' => 'localhost',
'username' => 'root',
'password' => '',
'database' => 'database_name',
'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
'dbprefix' => '',
'pconnect' => FALSE,
'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
'cache_on' => FALSE,
'cachedir' => '',
'char_set' => 'utf8',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
'swap_pre' => '',
'encrypt'  => FALSE,
'compress' => FALSE,
'stricton' => FALSE,
'failover' => array(),
'save_queries' => TRUE
 );
```

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1049): Unknown database '<studentsnotes>'

Filename: mysqli/mysqli_driver.php

Line Number: 202

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\Themeportal\application\controllers\Home.php
Line: 8
Function: __construct

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\Themeportal\index.php
Line: 318
Function: require_once

A Database Error Occurred

Unable to connect to your database server using the provided settings.

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/Themeportal/application/controllers/Home.php

Line Number: 8

Comment: set like this `'database' => 'studentsnotes',`

Comment: A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: file_get_contents(C:\xampp\htdocs\Themeportal\application\controllersapplication/config/verify.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Filename: controllers/Default_controllers.php

Line Number: 4

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\Themeportal\application\controllers\Default_controllers.php
Line: 4
Function: file_get_contents

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\Themeportal\application\controllers\Home.php
Line: 20
Function: require

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\Themeportal\index.php
Line: 318
Function: require_once

Comment: could you post your application\controllers\Home.php?check there you have error in `require_once`.

Answer (score 0):

first configure your database setting application/config/database.php

then your query will be

```
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('ts_themes');
    $this->db->where('theme_status',"1");
    $query=$this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
```